# Tailable cursor closing when reaching end of collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to stream some data from a MongoDB capped collection as follows:

```
var query = {};
var options = {tailable: true, awaitdata: true, numberOfRetries: Number.MAX_VALUE};

var stream = myColl.find(query, options).stream();

stream.on('data', function(doc){
    console.log(doc);
}).on('error', function (error){
    console.log(error);
}).on('close', function () {
    console.log('closed');
});
```

This prints the documents as expected but upon reaching the end of the collection the stream closes. Is it possible to prevent this from happening? I am looking to have the program print the data as it arrives in the collection, waiting at the end of the collection indefinitely for more data.

Comment: For some reason the `awaitdata: true` option causes this issue. I ran into this a few weeks ago. Try using just `{tailable: true}` for the options.

Comment: @BrianShamblen attempting results `var options = {tailable: true};` in the same issue. I have also tried `var stream = myColl.find().tailable().stream();` Did you get your code working a few weeks ago?

Comment: Yes, I needed to write an oplog monitor. I ran into the same issue, where the cursor kept closing. Removing the awaitdata option fixed it.

Comment: @BrianShamblen Strange how that solution doesn't work for me. Did you have any of the other options enabled (e.g. numberOfRetries)

Comment: No, just the one option. It's possible we're running different versions, which is why it works for me and not for you. I'm on 4.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. Turns out my issue was that I wasn't formatting my options correctly.

```
myColl.find().tailable(true, { awaitdata: true ,numberOfRetries:  Number.MAX_VALUE}).stream();
```

Is correct and works as expected.